# Visual Studio 2012 "Syntax Error"

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting the following errors when I attempt to compile my project in Visual Studio 2012:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.c
1>e:\main.c(28): warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\stdio.h(290) : see declaration of 'scanf'
1>e:\main.c(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>e:\main.c(31): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>e:\main.c(33): error C2065: 'answerMin' : undeclared identifier
1>e:\main.c(33): error C2065: 'answerMax' : undeclared identifier
1>e:\main.c(35): error C2065: 'answerMax' : undeclared identifier
1>e:\main.c(36): error C2065: 'answerMin' : undeclared identifier
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is the code in main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double a ;
double b ;
double ComputeMaximum( double, double ) ;
double ComputeMinimum( double, double ) ;

int main(void)
{

  printf("\nPlease enter two numeric values for comparison\n") ;

  scanf("%d%d", &a, &b );

  double answerMax = ComputeMaximum( a, b ) ;
  double answerMin = ComputeMinimum( a, b ) ;

  printf("Of %d and %d the minimum is %d and the maximum is %d\n", a, b, answerMin, answerMax ) ;

  printf("%d", answerMax ) ;
  printf("%d", answerMin ) ;

  system("pause");
  return 0;

}
```

Here is the code for ComputeMinimum.c

```
double ComputeMinimum( double a, double b )
{
  double result = 0 ;
  ( a > b ) ? ( b = result ) : ( a = result ) ;
  return result ;

}
```

Here is the code for ComputeMaximum.c

```
double ComputeMaximum(double a, double b)
{
  double result = 0 ;
  ( a > b ) ? ( a = result ) : ( b = result ) ;
  return result ;

}
```

Comment: In MS world, C is still C89 and all variables must be declared at the top of the function. Put up with that, or get a real C compiler.

Comment: Unrelated: You may want to take a longer look at ComputeMaximum and ComputeMinimum, as *neither* of them do anything except return 0. (and set one of the two by-value parameters to 0 in the process).

Comment: Oops, thank you David!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b );
```

must be

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b);
```

because `a` and `b` are doubles (with a space between values).

same for

```
printf("Of %d and %d the minimum is %d and the maximum is %d\n", a, b, answerMin, answerMax ) ;
```

change `%d` to `%f`

Also note that in

```
double ComputeMinimum( double a, double b )
{
  double result = 0 ;
  ( a > b ) ? ( b = result ) : ( a = result ) ;
  return result ;

}
```

`result` is always 0, change to

```
( a > b ) ? ( result = b ) : ( result = a ) ;
```

same for `computeMaximum`

And of course, you need to include the header containing those functions in `main.c` (compiler is warning about this fact)

Answer (score 1):

When using C you have to declare variable before any instruction or function call. Example:

```
int main(void)
{
    double answerMax;
    double answerMin;
    .....
    system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

About deprecated function. you can add  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING in your preprocessor definition in the project properties.