# Issues printing strings

Tags: c, string

We did this exercise in class today, but unfortunately, my code wasn't running properly. It won't print `string1`. My teacher also could not figure out why this was happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
char string1[20];
char string2[] = "It is almost end of semester!";
size_t idx;
int size;

printf("Enter string1:\n");
scanf_s("%s", string1);
size = sizeof(string2) / sizeof(char);
printf("\nString 1 is : %s\n\n", string1);
for (idx = 0; idx < size; idx++)
{
    printf("%c ", string2[idx]);
}
puts("");
system("pause");;
}
```

Comment: You have 2 semicolons at the end of `system("pause");;`

Comment: `scanf_s`, what is that?

Comment: @Broly, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Broly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Comment: It's just `scanf`, which is "unsafe" in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What happens, exactly? Seg fault? Empty output?

Comment: @Politank-Z, yeah, empty output.

Comment: Why are you using the size of string2's buffer to decide how many characters in string1 to print?

Comment: 1) You should generally use `strlen(string)`, not "sizeof (string_array)".  2) You should never divide by "sizeof (char)" - by definition, it's always "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scanf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) requires an extra parameter.

```
scanf_s("%s", string1, _countof(string1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `scanf_s` instead of `scanf` which, as Mr. Lynch correctly pointed out requires an additional parameter. You can accomplish the same thing with `scanf` itself. One approach is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    char string1[20];
    char string2[] = "It is almost end of semester!";
    size_t idx;
    int size;

    printf ("Enter string1:\n");
    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", string1);
    string[19] = 0;                            /* force null-termination of string1 */
    size = sizeof (string2) / sizeof (char);
    printf ("\nString 1 is : %s\n\n", string1);
    for (idx = 0; idx < size; idx++) {
        printf ("%c ", string2[idx]);
    }
    puts ("");
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/strprn
Enter string1:
scanf_s is not scanf

String 1 is : scanf_s is not scanf

I t   i s   a l m o s t   e n d   o f   s e m e s t e r !
```

**Note:** `main()` is type `int` not `void` no matter what ms lets you get away with. It returns a value as well.

Comment: I use `scanf_s` because scanf is "unsafe" and throws a warning that won't let me run the program.

Comment: Huh? 'scanf' is part of the C standard, is not unsafe, and will let your run your program. Just copy and paste what I posted and see.

Comment: VS 2014 throws a warning. I have to disables warnings to use scanf.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776519/visual-studio-2012-syntax-error

Comment: @Novaea - I suspect it is MS trying to protect programmers from having to learn C. There is nothing wrong with `scanf` -- period. C, is an exact language, that is where its power lies. It takes understanding what each part of a statement does, including the format string. While reading line input is better handled by `getline` or `fgets`, there is nothing wrong with `scanf`. It simply takes validating input, as should be done with any routine. Can `scanf_s` limit the amount of information read, sure, but does that mean `scanf` is unsafe - no. What does `string[19] = 0;` do?

Comment: I've been meaning to fix it to where I have the warnings permanently disabled. Or just switch to 2012.

Comment: No, you are fine either way.  I'm not saying you are wrong to use `scanf_s`, just understand it is not part of the normal C library making all code you write using it less portable. `Warnings` are **good**. Understanding **warnings** is even better. You now know you have to take care and validate input when using `scanf` (and with all other functions). You understand what your `scanf` warning means, and you are that much better a programmer for it. That's a good day of learning. :)